# Microsoft JScript runtime fault

Tags: javascript, c#, dom-events

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bittext.Text == "")
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Enter The value first or press the correct button')</script>");
    else
    {
        b = double.Parse(bittext.Text);
        Bytetext.Text = (b / 8).ToString();
        kbtext.Text = (b / 8192).ToString();
        mbtext.Text = (b / 8388608).ToString();
        gbtext.Text = (b / 8589934592).ToString();
        tbtext.Text = (b / 8796093022000).ToString();
    }
}
```

If I am running this web C# code without entering anything in bittext.Text, this throws an error named:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: 
>   The message received from the server could not be parsed.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `Response.Write()` for this, you need [`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx), like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alert",
  "alert('Enter The value first or press the correct button');", true);
```

`Response.Write()` just dumps that script tag whenever it is in the response, which makes for an invalid/unexpected format when the client goes to parse it, you want to properly execute a piece of JavaScript...above is the correct/provided mechanism for doing that.

Comment: +1, client is vomiting on the response.  Additionally he could solve this by adding a RequiredFieldValidator on this form and validating this crap client-side.

Comment: Agree with Moo-Juice, this validation should not be on the server (well it should be, but as a fallback for client-side validation). However, this is the correct answer.